# purposely causing bank conflicts for shared memory on CUDA device

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpu-shared-memory, bank-conflict

It is a mystery for me how shared memory on CUDA devices work. I was curious to count threads having access to the same shared memory. For this I wrote a simple program

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define nblc 13
#define nthr 1024

//------------------------@device--------------------

__device__ int inwarpD[nblc];

__global__ void kernel(){
__shared__ int mywarp;

mywarp=0;
for (int i=0;i<5;i++) mywarp += (10000*threadIdx.x+1);
__syncthreads();

inwarpD[blockIdx.x]=mywarp;
}
//------------------------@host-----------------------

int main(int argc, char **argv){
int inwarpH[nblc];
cudaSetDevice(2);

kernel<<<nblc, nthr>>>();

cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(inwarpH, inwarpD, nblc*sizeof(int), 0, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

for (int i=0;i<nblc;i++) printf("%i : %i\n",i, inwarpH[i]);
}
```

and ran it on K80 GPU. Since several threads are having access to the same shared memory variable I was expecting that this variable will be updated `5*nthr` times, albeit not at the same cycle because of the bank conflict. However, the output indicates that the `mywarp` shared variable was updated only 5 times. For each blocks different threads accomplished this task:

```
0 : 35150005
1 : 38350005
2 : 44750005
3 : 38350005
4 : 51150005
5 : 38350005
6 : 38350005
7 : 38350005
8 : 51150005
9 : 44750005
10 : 51150005
11 : 38350005
12 : 38350005
```

Instead, I was expecting

```
 523776*10000 + 5*1024 = 5237765120
```

for each block. Can someone kindly explain me where my understanding of shared memory fails. I would like also to know how would it be possible that all threads in one block access (update) the same shared variable. I know it is not possible at the same MP cycle. Serialization is fine for me because it is going to be a rare event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets walk through the ptx that it generates.

```
//Declare some registers
.reg .s32       %r<5>;
.reg .s64       %rd<4>;

// demoted variable
.shared .align 4 .u32 _Z6kernelv$__cuda_local_var_35411_30_non_const_mywarp;

//load tid in register r1
mov.u32         %r1, %tid.x;

//multiple tid*5000+5 and store in r2
mad.lo.s32      %r2, %r1, 50000, 5;

//store result in shared memory
st.shared.u32   [_Z6kernelv$__cuda_local_var_35411_30_non_const_mywarp], %r2;

///synchronize
bar.sync        0;

//load from shared memory and store in r3
ld.shared.u32   %r3, [_Z6kernelv$__cuda_local_var_35411_30_non_const_mywarp];

mov.u32         %r4, %ctaid.x;
mul.wide.u32    %rd1, %r4, 4;
mov.u64         %rd2, inwarpD;
add.s64         %rd3, %rd2, %rd1;

//store r3 in global memory
st.global.u32   [%rd3], %r3;
ret;
```

So basically

```
for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    mywarp += (10000*threadIdx.x+1);
```

is being optimized down to

```
mywarp=50000*threadIdx.x+5
```

so you're not experiencing a bank-conflict. You are experiencing a race-condition.

Comment: You're right, I don't know what I was thinking yesterday. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Thank you for your analysis. Some things are still not clear to me: i) when I put volatile attribute (as you suggested in your first answer) it changes the output little bit, e.g. last digit is not 5, but 7,8 sometimes. ii) Is it true that the race condition is resolved by allowing only one thread to modify the mywarp variable? iii) If I want all threads to participate I need atomicAdd()?

Comment: It depends exactly what you need. If you need a simple reduction (summation across threads), you could leave the data in register and then use a reduction method in shared memory. If you need each warp to uniquely update a single value, then yes, you need to use atomicAdd.